# Undefined name '_isAdLoaded'

Tags: flutter

estoy realizando un ejercicio con el que aprender a realiza runa calculadora IMC, además de añadir el anuncio interstitial que debe activarse una vez que el usuario hace clic en el botón de calcular su IMC.
He seguido una guía para colocarlos, en un archivo de prueba funciona bien trabajando con un único botón y un stateless widget, sin embargo en mi app, recibo el siguiente error:

> Undefined name '_isAdLoaded'. Try correcting the name to one that is
> defined, or defining the name.

junto con:

> Undefined name '_interstitialAd'.
> Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Calculator()));
}


class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
  Calculator({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    _initAd();
  }

  late InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
  bool _isAdLoaded = false;

  void _initAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
        request: AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
            onAdLoaded: onAdLoaded, onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {}));
  }

  void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd ad) {
    _interstitialAd = ad;
    _isAdLoaded = true;
  }

  @override
  _CalculatorState createState() => _CalculatorState();
}

class _CalculatorState extends State<Calculator> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String infoText = "";
  String imcText = "";
  TextEditingController pesoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController alturaController = TextEditingController();

  void _calcImc() {  
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[40],
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title: const Text("Calcula tu IMC"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              _resetFields();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      


            child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.teal),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Calcular IMC",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),

                onPressed: () {
                  if (_isAdLoaded) {
                    _interstitialAd.show();
                  }

                  /*if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    _calcImc();
                  }*/
                },
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 40,
```

He recortado los fragmentos de código correspondientes a la parte de calculos e interfaz para que sea más sencillo de identificar el problema, ya que los errores se dan en el evento onPressed del ElevatedButton.

Gracias.

Comment: es raro lo del mensaje de error en `_isAdLoaded` , porque si está declarado y con valor inicial, trata de definir el `_interstitialAd` de la misma manera que el `_isAdLoaded`

Comment: De momento no he podido solucionarlo definiendo el _interstitialAd, sigo sin encontrar el error. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el problema cae en que esta tratando de llamar un argumento privado (ya que posee un '_' al inicio del su nombre) y es por esto que no puede acceder a este, podrias intentar quitarle el guion bajo al nombre de tu argumento o creando un get publico que te devuelva el valor de este.

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de lo que comenta @Christian sobre que es un metodo privado. Debes de acceder a una variable de tu `StatefulWidget` de la siguiente manera:

```
if (widget.isAdLoaded) {
    widget.interstitialAd.show();
}
```